# Batch o Powershell para alinear particiones de un disco duro?

Tags: windows, batch, powershell, windows7

Buenas. Me preguntaba si sería posible alinear las particiones mediante un script de batch o powershell en Windows 7 en adelante.
Se que hay software de terceros que lo hacen pero sería posible hacerlo mediante un script?

Supongo que llevaría tiempo.

No sé si sería factible, pero el procedimiento creo que podría ser el siguiente:

- Ver si hay espacio suficiente en el disco actual o un disco externo para hacer una copia temporal del contenido de las particiones a alinear.
- poner el conteido de la partición de sistema en C: por si acaso y borrar la particion de sistema (la de 100MB)
- hacer una copia del contenido de las particiones.
- Borrar particiones guardando la configuración previa de cada uan para crearlas igual después.
- Crear las particiones ya alineandolas debidamente.
- Volver a copiar el contenido de las particiones y copiar el contenido de "sistema" de nuevo en la partición si se quisiera.

Sería algo así posible? Existe algo parecido?